# Fault Velocity of centre of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

Consider two cases :

1. The velocity of a small ball coming down a wedge when it reaches the ground is simply (2gh)½ where 'h' is height of wedge .( Given it's initial velocity was zero )
2. But in case , if the ball rolls , then there will be change in it's velocity at down of wedge because rotational kinetic energy will also be included .

But my question is that why the rotational kinetic energy , other rotational terms , etc can change the velocity as so ; because we know that the centre of mass of a sphere never goes in any rotational motion and always follow translational motion . Why the rotational parameters interfere in the second case ?

Comment: Why do you think you can ignore the rotational energy of the ball?  The ball consists of more than its center and the whole ball contains rotational energy that cannot be ignored.

Comment: But I am ignoring only rotational kinetic energy of centre of mass and not the whole ball , because I want to calculate velocity of centre of mass .